# How to select date,month,year from the dropdown in qtp

Tags: qtp

Please help me out for the following doubt how to select the particular date,day,year from the drop down  option in qtp.can anyone help me to come out of this from,explain the date function in qtp.

Comment: Is it a website or a .NET/Java app?

Comment: Reaaaally not clear what you're asking here. In what format are you getting/specifying the date to be selected? Are you just having trouble parsing this date into its constituent parts, or are you also having trouble identifying and interacting with the relevant UI controls? If it's just the parsing, show us your input data and what code you've tried. If it's also the UI controls and a web app post some relevant HTML.

Comment: Tomorrow, I´ll post a question "How do I do the amount entry and calculation" with body "Please help it does not work sho meh da codez" to improve the standards around here :-((